# Where to find a hard crackme

Tags: obfuscation, unpacking, crackme

I'd like to improve my skill as a reverse engineer. And thus I am looking for a location to find these.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/about). This “question” is a request for recommendations that doesn't fit the format of the site: it cries for a list of links, not for answers — and a list of links is what you've been getting. Stack Exchange is for questions like “I'm trying to reverse this crackme, and I tried techniques A and B but they produced this strange result, what does it mean?”. Please read our [faq#dontask] for generic advice.

Comment: We can add suggested crackme websites to the new crackme tag-wiki.  But if you add some criteria (language, platform) and some particular challenges (anti-debug, VM-aware, IDT hooking), this could be considered a more legitimate question

Comment: I'm actually pretty happy with the answers.
I dont see how this question is any different to somebody asking about what are the state of art tools to do this or that.

Comment: Asking for a tool with specific requirements can have a single or more definitive answers which can be objectively evaluated on the basis of the specified requirements. Asking for a "hard" problem is impossible to answer by everybody other than yourself because of the fundamental question; What is "hard" ? Something that may be hard for you may be easy for another. There is no way to objectively evaluate the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a just closed reverse engineering challenge that was posted by Halvar Flake:
http://addxorrol.blogspot.kr/2013/01/encouraging-female-reverse-engineers.html

The winner and a link to her very detailed and well written report is linked on this page:
http://addxorrol.blogspot.kr/2013/03/congratulations-marion.html

This is much more difficult than most crackme's that I have encountered and is an example of a complex and obfuscated piece of Windows malware.

Answer (score 7):

Also you should check http://crackmes.de/ They have a huge list that you can sort by difficulty.

Answer (score 6):

open an account if you don't already have at forum.tuts4you.com, then browse to http://forum.tuts4you.com/forum/37-crackmes-unpackmes-keygenmes/ I believe that you will find many that you will like.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the crackmes and tuts4u sites some conferences have reverse engineering challenges. They are typically harder than the average crackmes. [AthCon](http://www.athcon.org/) recently put up a challenge. Here's a [link](http://www.athcon.org/AthCon_2013_RE_Challenge.zip) to the zip if you are interested. *I haven't personally done the challenge myself, so I don't know the skill level.*